# Leaflet.js Adding layers from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET website housing an instance of a Leaflet map which is set up to display data. I have drop-downs which on change fire events through jQuery, these in turn take the drop-down values and pass them to a Web Service which retrieves new data from the server. This data is geoJson data and is being returned in the form of a string. Trying to apply this new data to the map does not work. Here is the code, I know that what is coming back is correct and I have output it to a Div, copied it and loaded it manually and it has worked fine. Tearing my hair out over this now.

I'm outputting the return to a div to prove it works which it does...

```
$("#MainContent_DropDownList1").change(function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: "services/AJAXMapping.asmx/GetNewData",
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        data: { species: $(this).val() },
        error: function (err) {

            alert("Error: " + err.responseText.toString())

        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#testarea").html(data);
            geojson.clearLayers();

            geojson = L.geoJson((data), {
                style: choroStyle,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't parse your json-string to an object.

```
geojson = L.geoJson((JSON.parse(data)), {
    style: choroStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Or instead of `JSON.parse(data)` you can use `$.parseJSON(data)` as you are using jquery.

You can also set the `dataType` of your ajax call to `json` but then you have to transform your data object back to a string if you still want to output the geojson data to a div.
You can do this with `JSON.stringify(data)`

If this doesn't solve your problem please post the error message you get.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was tearing my hair out over this. The data was coming back from the web service as a string of Json however it was being wrapped in XML. I parsed the string as XML, got the inner string then parsed it as json using the jQuery functions. I'll update this with the code solution tomorrow when I get to work in the hope it might help others.